# Error requesting from angular to LinkedIn OAuth API

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular8, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement LinkedIn OAuth authorization API in my angular application. I made a simple GET request to the Linkedin authorization API. But it was blocked by CORS policy. I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in the headers but still I am getting the same issue. Please check the below code, screen shot and help to fix the issue.

[image]

[image]

```
getAuthorization() {
const httpParams = new HttpParams().append('response_type', 'code')
  .append('client_id', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
  .append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200/home')
  .append('scope', 'r_liteprofile r_emailaddress w_member_social');

const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

this.httpClient.get('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization', { headers: httpHeaders, params: httpParams })
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.accessToken = data;
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow Origin is set by bakckend, that is linkedin in your case. you must have registered a application with linkedin for that client id. So my guess is you won't be able to access that api from localhost. You need to check it on domain which you have registered with linkedin for that client id.